# Getting KeyError : 'callable_inputs' when trying to save a TF model in S3 bucket

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using sagemaker 2.5.1 and tensorflow 2.3.0
The weird part is that the same code worked before, the only change that I could think of is the new release of the two libraries

Comment: I have exactly same problem, pasted my question here: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/1478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually coming from smdebug version 0.9.1
Downgrading to 0.8.1 solves the issue

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug with SageMaker.

I'm assuming you are using a `TensorFlow` estimator to train the model. Something like this:

```
estimator = TensorFlow(
    entry_point='script.py',   
    role=role,  
    train_instance_count=1,   
    train_instance_type='ml.p3.2xlarge',  
    framework_version='2.3.0',   
    py_version='py37',  
    script_mode=True,
    hyperparameters={
        'epochs': 100,  
        'batch-size': 256,  
        'learning-rate': 0.001
    } 
)
```

If that's the case, either TensorFlow 2.2 it TensorFlow 3.3 is causing this error when debugger callbacks are enabled. To fix the issue, you can set the `debugger_hook_config` to `False`:

```
estimator = TensorFlow(
    entry_point='script.py',   
    role=role,  
    train_instance_count=1,   
    train_instance_type='ml.p3.2xlarge',  
    framework_version='2.3.0',   
    py_version='py37',  
    script_mode=True,
    debugger_hook_config=False,
    hyperparameters={
        'epochs': 100,  
        'batch-size': 256,  
        'learning-rate': 0.001
    } 
)
```